# How do I assign a subdomain.domain.com, domain.com and domain.com/[path] to three different Next JS projects

Tags: next.js, url-routing, next.js13, web-hosting, nextjs-dynamic-routing

I have a domain called domain.com for example

I have three different projects for three different purposes and I am using Next JS.

These three projects all have their separate purposes.

The first of these repos is a landing page project and it should have domain.com

The second repo for every user personal page and I want the  domain to be in the format: domain.com/${username}. The reason is cos the {username} is a dynamic path for each user's page

The third domain is for the main app itself and I want it to have app.domain.com

How can I achieve these complex domain configurations.

I have been able to setup the subdomain for the separate main app on app.domain.com but I don't know how to achieve the personal user pages domain

Comment: Sounds like you need a reverse proxy, maybe [nginx](https://www.nginx.com/) or similar. Your DNS should have `domain.com` and `app.domain.com` pointing to the IP of the server that hosts your reverse proxy. Then, configure your reverse proxy to forward requests to each of these domains to the relevant application.